# Is my interpretation on the specific replacement in a solution is correct or not - Mixtures and Concentrations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the question and solution -

A container contains 40 litres of milk. From this container 4 litres of milk was taken out and replaced by water. This process  was repeated further two times . How much milk is now contained by the container.

Solution --

Dilution -- concentration of 
milk is 36/40 - again this is two times more than - the net concentration of milk is 36/40 * 36/40 * 36/40.

Thus, the net amount of milk in 40 litres is 40 * 36^3/ 40^3.

---

My doubt is how they can assume that the concentration of milk at second time is 36/40. After the replacement, the milk concentration level is already 36/40. Now, we will be further diluting it. How is this possible to have milk concentration 36/40 each times? If I correlate this with the counting - permutation - if the events are dependent then the next event will be reduced from the 36/40 part. It cannot be independent events - not every time we will be taking out exactly 4 litres of milk. Next time, it is a solution and not a pure milk. How is this answer possible? If this is not the correct answer then please tell me the appropriate answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Each dilution is achieved by replacing $4~\text{L}$ of the solution with $4~\text{L}$ of water.

The first dilution reduces the concentration of milk to

$$\frac{(40 - 4)~\text{L}}{40~\text{L}} = \frac{36}{40} = \frac{9}{10} = 0.9$$

Since

$$\frac{9}{10} \cdot 40~\text{L} = 36~\text{L}$$

you now have $40~\text{L}$ of a solution that contains $36~\text{L}$ of milk. When you dilute it the second time, you pour off $4~\text{L}$ of this $90\%$ milk solution, thereby removing an additional

$$0.9(4~\text{L}) = 3.6~\text{L}$$

of milk, which is replaced by water, leaving you with $(40 - 4 - 3.6)~\text{L} = 32.4~\text{L}$ of milk.  The concentration of milk after two dilutions is

$$\frac{32.4~\text{L}}{40~\text{L}} = \frac{0.9(36)}{40} = \frac{0.9[0.9(40)]}{40} = 0.9^2 = 0.81$$

In the third dilution, you replace $4~\text{L}$ of this $81\%$ milk solution with $4~\text{L}$ of water, thereby removing an additional

$$0.81(4~\text{L}) = 3.24~\text{L}$$

of milk from the solution, leaving you with $(40 - 4 - 3.6 - 3.24)~\text{L} = 29.16~\text{L}$ of milk in the solution.  Thus, the concentration of milk after three dilutions is

$$\frac{29.16~\text{L}}{40~\text{L}} = \frac{0.9(32.4)}{40} = \frac{0.9[0.9(36)]}{40} = \frac{0.9\{0.9[0.9(40)]\}}{40} = 0.9^3 = 0.729$$

Thus, the concentration of milk in the solution is reduced to $90\%$ after the first dilution, $81\%$ after the second dilution, and $72.9\%$ after the third dilution.  The reason the concentration is $9/10$ as much as it was previously after each dilution is that by replacing $1/10$ of the solution by water each time, you are replacing $1/10$ of the milk in the solution with water leaving you with $1 - 1/10 = 9/10$ as much milk in the solution as you had previously.

Comment: good solution. Only part that is missing for me is the reason the concentration is 9/10 as much as it was previously - can you please elaborate on it. Is it true only for 1/10 solution if they would be taking out 8 litres instead of 4 litres -then I can't do a cube is it?

Comment: I edited the final sentence of my answer to explain why you have $9/10$ as much milk after each dilution. Replacing $8~\text{L}$ of the $40~\text{L}$ solution removes $1/5$ of the milk at each dilution.  First, you remove $8~\text{L}$ of milk, leaving you with an $80\%$ milk solution.  You then remove $0.8(8~\text{L}) = 6.4~\text{L}$, leaving you with a solution that is $(40 - 8 - 6.4)/40 \cdot 100\% = 64\%$ milk.  In the third dilution, you remove $0.8[0.8(8~\text{L})] = 5.12~\text{L}$ of milk, leaving you with a milk concentration of $(40 - 8 - 6.4 - 5.12)/40 = 0.512 = 0.8^3$.